# Какой знак препинания следует поставить на месте пропуска?

Tags: запятые, бсп, подчинительная-связь, запятые-или-двоеточие

Звук был настолько резок, что ему показалось (?) перепонки сейчас лопнут.

Здесь как бы опущен подчинительный союз "что". Становится ли от этого предложение сложным бессоюзным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможна постановка **двоеточия** (основной знак) или **тире** (которое часто его замещает):

***Звук был настолько резок**, что ему показалось — // **перепонки сейчас лопнут**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Это **сложное** предложение (сложная синтаксическая конструкция), **три** предикативные основы. **По [Лопатину](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)** предложение состоит **из двух блоков**.

**Первый блок**: Звук был **настолько** резок, **что** ему показалось. Связь подчинительная, местоименно-союзная, союз ***ЧТО*** со значением **следствия**.

**Второй блок**: *Перепонки сейчас лопнут*. Простое предложение.

2. Между блоками **бессоюзная** связь, отношения **изъяснительные** (можно заменить союзом ***ЧТО***). Ставится двоеточие или тире, **авторский выбор** по контексту.

Я бы выбрала **тире**: события развиваются **динамично**, а двоеточие предполагает наличие предупредительной **паузы** (остановка в речи, интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю).

**Примечание.**  Если есть сомнения **в границе** между блоками, то я поясню. Бессоюзная связь не имеет ограничений, в то время как первый блок — эо **нерасчлененный** тип СПП в связи с наличием местоименно-союзной связи (его делить на части **нельзя**).

Также на границе между блоками  при произношении делается подчеркнутая **пауза,** которую нужно обозначить **более сильным** знаком, чем запятая (двоеточием или тире).